# Aggregate associatations to JSON only if they exist in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to return a "complete" `user` object via JSON from an API that is backed by a Postgres SQL database. `users` can belong to `teams`, which are stored as `memberships` in a table.

My tables are setup like this:

```
Users
   id   |        email         | password |   name   | created_at 
--------+----------------------+----------+----------+------------
 user_1 | user-one@example.com | password | User One | 2015-09-17
 user_2 | user-two@example.com | password | User Two | 2015-09-17

Teams
   id   |        email         |   name   | created_at 
--------+----------------------+----------+------------
 team_1 | team-one@example.com | Team One | 2015-09-17
 team_2 | team-two@example.com | Team Two | 2015-09-17

Memberships
   id   | team_id | user_id | created_at 
--------+---------+---------+------------
 memb_1 | team_1  | user_1  | 2015-09-17
 memb_2 | team_1  | user_2  | 2015-09-17
```

With my current query:

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.email,
  users.name,
  users.created_at,
  json_agg(teams.*) AS teams
FROM users, teams, memberships
WHERE users.id=$[id]
AND users.id=memberships.user_id
AND teams.id=memberships.team_id
GROUP BY
  users.id,
  users.email,
  users.name,
  users.created_at
```

For `user_1` that ends up returning:

```
{
  "id": "user_1",
  "email": "user-one@example.com",
  "name": "User One",
  "created_at": "2015-09-17T07:00:00.000Z",
  "teams": [
    {
      "id": "team_1",
      "email": "team-one@example.com",
      "name": "Team One",
      "created_at": "2015-09-17"
    },
    {
      "id": "team_2",
      "email": "team-two@example.com",
      "name": "Team Two",
      "created_at": "2015-09-17"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the problem is, if I add a new `user_3`, they don't have any memberships yet, so the query ends up returning nothing, since there's nothing to `AND users.id = memberships.user_id` join on.

How can I fix this query so that when a user doesn't have any memberships it ends up with just an empty `"teams": []` array?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead, You will get null if not matching on the other tables.

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.email,
  users.name,
  users.created_at,
  json_agg(teams.*) AS teams
FROM users
LEFT JOIN memberships
 ON users.id=memberships.user_id
LEFT JOIN teams
 ON teams.id=memberships.team_id
WHERE users.id=$[id]
GROUP BY
  users.id,
  users.email,
  users.name,
  users.created_at
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks! Is there a way to get rid of the `null` that shows up in the results? Right now this results in `"teams": [null]`.

Comment: Ended up solving the `null` issue by using a conditional: `CASE
        WHEN count(teams.*) = 0 THEN '[]'::JSON
        ELSE json_agg(teams.*) END
      AS teams`